# How to provide data to Fuel UX datagrid from Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fuelux

I'd like to use the Fuel UX datagrid to display some data I am retrieving from my database.  The page is served from a ruby on rails server.

The javascript example code for building the data object:

```
        var dataSource = new StaticDataSource({
            columns: [{
                property: 'toponymName',
                label: 'Name',
                sortable: true
            }, {
                property: 'countrycode',
                label: 'Country',
                sortable: true
            }, {
                property: 'population',
                label: 'Population',
                sortable: true
            }, {
                property: 'fcodeName',
                label: 'Type',
                sortable: true
            }],
            data: sampleData.geonames,
            delay: 250
        });

        $('#MyGrid').datagrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            stretchHeight: true
        });

        $('#datagrid-reload').on('click', function () {
            $('#MyGrid').datagrid('reload');
        });
```

If I am understanding the code, I am going to be defining my columns and some attributes in the columns object inside of the dataSource variable, and the data object is being loaded by sampleData.geonames.

The sampleData is [here](https://raw.github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/2.0.0/sample/data.js)

What can I do using the rails conventions to replace the sampleData.geonames?  I tried tweaking this a few ways to load rails objects in to here.

For example, I modified my columns' property fields to correspond to some properties of my User model.  I tried replacing the

```
data: sampleData.geonames,
```

to

```
data: <%= @users.to_json %>,
```

I'm a little restricted on gems and versions, currently using Rails 2.3.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the datagrid to make a background AJAX request to load the data from your app, please see this tutorial which will be closer to what you need:

http://dailyjs.com/2012/10/29/fuel-ux

This would have the benefit of an immediate page load followed by asynchronous loading of data.

If you would rather stick with the StaticDataSource approach just embed a small script on your page similar to this:

```
<script>
  var myData = { ... };
</script>
```

Then, load that with:

```
var dataSource = new StaticDataSource({
  columns: [ ... ],
  data: myData,
  delay: 250
});
```

Comment: could you provide an example of what `...` in myData should look like?

Comment: Sure, it should be an array of objects.  Example: https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/blob/master/sample/data.js#L9-L1907

Comment: That associates with the columns and data options on the datagrid as seen here: https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/blob/master/index.html#L114-L136